# Replace tabelator by two spaces in answer editor

Tags: feature-request, editor

Many users copy&pastes their code into the answer editor, which sets the tab size to something like four spaces treated as single character. This screws the indentation up, the code often needs to be scrolled right and back to read. Since the tab can be inserted only by pasting anyway, wouldn't it be practical to replace it by two or four hard spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Bad formatting is going to happen no matter how many automatic corrections are done.

A Python problem that can't be reproduced because of automatic changes to the indentation would be a Bad Thing(tm).

If someone wants excellent, free help, the burden's on them to format things in a legible way.

Comment: But still: if I try to improve formating by holding `delete` key :-) to avoid horizontal scrolling, the text starts to jump left very fast if the delete starts to eat tabs. And if I need to place tab somewhere else, tough luck, only by pasting. Maybe `Ctr+tab` could insert the tab in text? I can live without that, just a suggestion.

Comment: @JanTuroň What about just converting all the tabs to spaces in a separate editor?  (Or not using them in the first place, when applicable.)

Comment: can be, unless someone else's post needs edit. To ask them is usually longer process than a quick direct edit. In that case, I usually don't bother, but I (and perharps someone else) could if the tab was fixed.

Comment: @JanTuro: Personally, if I see a badly indented question, I attempt to fix it by running it through PhpStorm. If it works, great, edit it, now look at it again. If it doesn't, too bad. This question isn't worth my time. OP didn't even put the effort to make the question look decent. Why should I?